# iReport gráficos dinámicos

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

El inconveniente que tengo es que quiero realizar una tabla de lineas de acuerdo al mes buscado en un rango de fechas pero quiero que la gráfica se repita de acuerdo al mes.

Tengo una consulta que me trae el mes, día y cuantas incidentes por día, la gráfica la hace bien pero para hacer que se repita por cada mes que hay, en ese rango no se como, ahorita los tengo uno por uno osea que si quiero tres meses hago gráfica por gráfica si quiero 12 hago doce gráficas.
quiero que sea solo una y que itere de acuerdo a los meses.[image: Ese es un ejemplo solo que quiero que se repita por el rango de meses]

Un ejemplo de marzo

Uso iReport 5.5.1, he visto que tengo que agrupar los meses en alguna parte del reporte pero no veo en donde.

Comment: Yo haría en un report la consulta que te devuelva los meses, y en un subreporte haría la consulta para obtener los datos de ese mes y pintaría ahí la gráfica. Al subreport le puedes envíar el mes como parámetro.

Comment: deje de trabajar con java de hace 2 años, pero recuerdo que cuando empece a realizar reportes me sacaba canas esta librería, si quieres un consejo personal busca una que hagas todo manual, te darás cuenta de las posibilidades es mucho mejor que trabajar con esta que te limita de mil cosas.

Answer (score 0):

Hola por lo que puede entender lo que tu quieres realizar es algo como lo siguiente:

[image: Tabla de Lineas Multiples]

he encontrado un tutorial bastante bueno en el siguiente [link](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/creating-multi-axis-charts-ireport-designer), el único problema es que esta en ingles y se que si estas en la comunidad de español pues espera obviamente ayuda en español, pero puedes dar click derecho y traducir a español y seguir el tuto sin ningún problema, espero te sirva.

Saludos.

Comment: Si el enlace se rompe, la respuesta se hace imposible de usar en el futuro. Las respuestas deben procurar ser autocontenidas; en estos casos, deben incluir los detalles relevantes de la solución EN la respuesta.